# Check if a directory exists in subdirectory in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, directory

What command checks if a directory exists in another path using shell script?

I searched about this, but all I could find was checking if a directory exists in "current" directory.

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  # found "any" directory
fi
```

This doesn't satisfy when I want to know if "any" directory exist inside of another directory.

```
if [ -d "./PATH/$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  # found "any" directory in subdirectory
fi
```

Apparently this did not work. This still checks from current working directory, not the path I have given.

Any suggestions?

I would like to use this in if condition, so answering with keeping that form would be helpful.

**EDIT**

In shell script I added as following:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -ld ./smth/world/
echo DIRECTORY=$DIRECTORY

if [ -d "./smth/$DIRECTORY/" ]; then
   echo hi
else
   echo nope
fi
```

in the current directory, I have a directory called "smth". Inside that "smth" I created a dummy directory "world"

**EDIT #2**

After I added the dot in front of path, I get the following:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 (myname) (myname) 4096 Sep  5 14:39 ./smth/world/
DIRECTORY=
found
```

BUT after I delete the world directory inside of smth directory, still get "found".

Comment: Your question is unclear. Assuming that your variable `DIRECTORY` contains the word *world*. The expressions ` [ -d "/smth/$DIRECTORY" ]` or alternatively `[[ -d /smth/$DIRECTORY ]]` both test, whether the directory `/smth/world` (absolute path) exists. If your test doesn't show the desired result, I suggest that you - just for testing purpose do a `ls -ld /smth/world` and a `echo DIRECTORY=$DIRECTORY` right before the `if` statement. If your goal is to test something different, please rephrase your question.

Comment: I edited my question to what you told me, and I get the result as following

Answer (score 6):

That's the other way. `./` if for a directory relative to the current directory, `/` if for a fully specified directory, i.e.:

If you provide a full path to the directory, you need to remove the dot:

```
if [ -d "/full/path/to/smth/$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  # found 
fi
```

If the `PATH` directory is relative to your current one, the dot must be kept:

```
if [ -d "./smth/$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  # found
fi
```

If the `DIRECTORY` variable is unset, the previous commands will check if there is a directory named `PATH` in the `smth` one, if the `DIRECTORY` variable is set, the test will only succeed if there is a subdirectory with that value under `smth`.

`echo $DIRECTORY` will tell you if the `DIRECTORY` variable is set.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't try that after almost 30 min. My rank is not high enough to upvote, but thank you so much!

Comment: Hmm... I don't know why but that always gives me false. I made a directory in "PATH" then wrote simple code "echo hi", but doesn't print anything.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the precise commands you ran and their output.

Comment: Have done so. There's really not much to see, but that's the code I used.